# Getting hold of a Silverlight Out of Browser Application Id

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

I'm trying to launch a SL4 OOB application from the web browser. I'm currently trying to achieve this by associating a file type with sllauncher.exe and then adding the SL4 OOB application id as a parameter. The SL4 OOB application is launched when the specific file type is downloaded from the browser, but in order for me to create an installer I need to be able to retrieve the application id so I can update the registry entry for the file type association.Does anyone know how the application id is generated or if it's possible to force a specific application id to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that this won't be easy...
There's a method **Deployment.GetAppIdForUri** which sounds like it does exactly what you need, but unfortunately it is marked **SecurityCritical** so you can't use it.

A hack that might work is this:
When the app is installed OOB, you might use Application.Current.Host.Source or something like that plus a bit of substring magic to get the app ID. Unfortunately, I'm not able to test that right now because I'm uninstalling the VS2010 RC on this machine right now ;-)
Anyway, if that works, you might take the ID and write it into IsoStore for later use.

Forcing a specific ID for the app would be nice, but I think it's not possible.

Cheers, Alex

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut file of Silverlight OOB application includes the application id. Retrieving the application id from the shortcut file is work to me.